# How to retrieve a facebook photo of a different user, is this possible?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to retrieve a photo of a user different from the logged one, here what I did:

1. I have 2 different users that granted "user_photos" permission to my app
2. I'm able to retrieve the photos uploaded by USER_1 through the API

   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/me/photos/uploaded?access_token=USER_1_TOKEN
3. Let's suppose I'm interested in the photo with id PHOTO_ID_123 (privacy public) and I want USER_2 to be able to view that photo. I should call the following API:

   https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/PHOTO_ID_123?access_token=USER_2_TOKEN

(note the different token user in the latter call)

The issue is that now I'm getting the following error from FB:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
    "type": "GraphMethodException",
    "code": 100,
    "fbtrace_id": "GmYciGz/Mpd"
  }
}
```

These two users are mutual friends on facebook, but since the photo is public I expect to be accessible even in case the two users are not mutual friends.
Of course the following API call

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.5/PHOTO_ID_123?access_token=USER_1_TOKEN
```

is working as expected (it does return photo related data). If USER_2 try to access PHOTO_ID_123 from browser (inside facebook website), he can see the photo.

What am I missing? Is this even possible? To me it seems possible from fb doc: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/photo/

> Permissions
>
> Any valid access token can read photos on a public Page. A page access
>   token can read all photos posted to or posted by that Page. A user
>   access token can read any photo your application created on behalf of
>   that user. **A user's photos can be read if the owner has granted the
>   user_photos or user_posts permission.** A user access token may read a
>   photo that user is tagged in if they have granted the user_photos or
>   user_posts permission. However, in some cases the photo's owner's
>   privacy settings may not allow your application to access it.

Thanks

Comment: if it works with USER_2_TOKEN, but not with USER_1_TOKEN, i guess the answer should be clear ;)

Comment: Actually it's the opposite. Btw could you please explain your thought? As explained in the question I expect it to work because the photo is public (If i browse that photo from the browser of the second user from I can access it)

Comment: my bad. either way, just because it is public does not mean you should be able to get it with the API or a token of another user.

Comment: check out my answer for an explanation. if you think it´s not correct, you should file a bug.

Answer (score 0):

If i authorize an App with `user_photos`, i would not want any other App User to be able to see my photos - at least not without my permission per photo. So it does make sense not to be able to access photos of one user with the Token of another.

You could let the User select some photos and store it on your server if you want that to happen. Just because something is public on facebook.com does not mean you can grab it with the API, that would make a lot of permissions pointless.

Comment: Thanks, do you think if I store the facebook cdn URL on my server instead of the actual photo is against facebook policies?

Comment: that is a bad idea, because the CDN URL can change (at least that is what facebook employees said). you should never store the CDN URL.

Comment: Yes I know, so the only chance is to save those photos to my server?

Comment: yes, but you should make it clear to the user that you are doing it